# Automating "Formula to Value" in LibreOffice via UNO in Python

Tags: python, libreoffice, uno

I am regularly receiving a spreadsheet from an external source (via google docs) that I have to convert into a local (kinda proprietary) format. To do that, I have written a script that can convert the spreadsheet as an ODS file into the needed format (non-ODS).
This script needs to interact with a lot of higher-level business-specific PHP stuff, so I use PhpSpreadsheet for this purpose (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/).

This PHP library does theoretically everything I need, but it cannot deal with overly complex spreadsheets without taking an gigantic amount of time dealing with all the cross-referencing formulas. To speed up the processing in the script, I manually prepare the ODS file by hand by converting all formulas to values (Select all Cells in the needed Sheets, then trigger [Data] > [Calculate] > [Formula to Value]) in the needed sheets. Then I delete all the unneeded sheets (which otherwise only contain source-data for the replaced formulas). The resulting file is a lot smaller and does not contain any formulas. The execution of the PHP script finishes within a few seconds with the simplified spreadsheet file, while it runs out of memory after a long while with the original spreadsheet file.

I now seek to automate this process of converting all the formulas to values using a new python script (This needs to happen on a linux server, so my best bet would be a headless libreoffice controlled via an UNO socket in python, correct?).
So far I have managed to connect to the libreoffice UNO socket and manipulate the cells via the old OpenOffice-API (https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/module-ix.html).
My current big question is:

**How do I access the UI-`Formula to Value`-functionality on all cells of a sheet at once via the UNO API in Python?**

I have tried searching the old OpenOffice API documentation for this for a while, but so far I cannot find what I am looking for.

Currently the python script looks (in essence) like this:

```py
import uno

localContext = uno.getComponentContext()

resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", 
    localContext 
)

context = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")

serviceManager = context.ServiceManager

desktop = serviceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context)

# com.sun.star.lang.XComponent / com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetDocument
document = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

# com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheets / XNameAccess
sheets = document.getSheets()

# com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheet   
# https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSpreadsheet.html
sheet = sheets.getByName('OneOfTheSheets')

#print(sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:AP1000"))

# WAY TOO SLOW AND DESTRUCTIVE:
for row in range(0, 1000):
    for column in range(0, 42):
        cell = sheet.getCellByPosition(column, row)
        cell.setFormula(cell.getString())
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `range(0, 1000)` but still, how about `.setDataArray(.getDataArray())`?

Comment: Huh, that was way easier then expexted, I should have asked way earlier.
I have seen that functions, but did not recognize them to be what I was looking for.
`cellRange = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:AP1000")` `cellRange.setDataArray(cellRange.getDataArray())` did the trick perfectly.
If you want to, you can write that as an answer, which I would then accept.
Thank you.